# Who owns Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, stackexchange

Basically, I started by visiting Stack Overflow to ask questions, I thought you could ask anything but then realised that it was only for programming and there are sub-sites like:

- math.stackexchange.com
- raspberrypi.stackexchange.com
- superuser.com

Which all pretty much have the same defining UI (although, some are unique to the topic).

So my question is this:

Does someone own the entire sites, or, are there individual people who think of a topic which could be useful or popular and decide to open it by themselves following some StackExchange rules?

Comment: Site proposals start at http://area51.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Sathya So when a user proposes it, and, it get's accepted... Do they become Admin of that particular proposal?

Comment: no, they don't. Stack Exchange Inc owns the site. The content is licensed under Creative Commons.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Does someone own the entire sites, or

The sites are all "owned" by [Stack Exchange Inc](http://stackexchange.com/about). All user contributions are licensed  under [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)(with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)).

> are there individual people who think of a topic which could be useful or popular and decide to open it by themselves following some StackExchange rules?

It's not done by a single person - the steps include:

- Propose the site topic on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)
- Define the site topic
- Gain commitment to the site by fellow users.

You can read the requirements for proposing, defining, commitment & launch process over at the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)